# Time travel books with a ship's crew travelling off-world to review physical historical records which turn out to have been manipulated

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

Looking for author/title of time travel books (trilogy?).

It is a dying planet story, and time travel is regulated/policed (under government control).  Books and historical records are kept off-world, so a ship goes to that location to review physical records for evidence that planet is dying.  Once in the library of records, footprints are noted on the otherwise dusty floor, suggesting historical records have been manipulated.

After landing on the planet, the ship becomes covered with vegetation, which presents the crew with challenges once they try to leave.

Contents also include a glossary of names and aliases of crew members.

Answer (score 6):

There is a trilogy of books by Crawford Kilian: *The Fall of the Republic* (1978), *Empire of Time* (1987) and *Rogue Emperor* (1989).

In *The Fall of the Republic*, the USA are under martial law, the only thing preventing total collapse are the Trainables, people who can absorb and perfectly recall vast amounts of information. A scientist discovers a way to open portals to different times, when they are actually alternate Earths at different stages of time.

In a plane they call Ulru, it's a scorched and lifeless future, a crew of Trainables goes there to a record storage to determine what brought that plane to that end, to prevent it happening to their Earth. I don't remember a part of them being caught by vegetation and vaguely recall that the data there might have manipulated.

[image: "Fall of the Republic" cover, astronaut in a red suit facing a tank in a corridor][image: "Empire of Time" cover, blue canine creatures looking at a subway][image: "Rogue Emperor" cover, orange aircraft in front of pillars]

Comment: One book in the series, *The Empire of Time*, was the subject of a [previous question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38349/id-a-novel-in-which-the-protagonist-was-sent-back-in-time-to-pull-forward-indivi), but I don't think that makes this a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds similar to [*The Chronicles of Solace*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42700-the-chronicles-of-solace), a trilogy by Roger MacBride Allen, first published in 2000. From the [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553574973) summary of volume one, *The Depths of Time* :

> The settled universe is filled with terraformed worlds linked by timeshafts -- temporal wormholes in deep space. These timeshafts are the only way to travel the vast distances between the stars.
>
> The Chronologic Patrol is charged with guarding the timeshaft wormholes and preventing time paradoxes at all costs. But one critical mission ends in disaster, turning Anton Koffield, captain of the Upholder, into a dark legend....
>
> As ships carrying relief supplies to a crippled planet approach a timeshaft, they are mercilessly set upon by mysterious attackers -- their crews are murdered and the sanctity of time itself is at risk.
>
> In response, Koffield is forced to do the unthinkable: he must stop the invasion by destroying the timeshaft. Marooned eighty years in the future, he lives as a cursed figure, the villain who killed a world.

[image: Novel cover, space station in universe background]

I vaguely remember reading this book in high school, and there's a part in the third book, *The Ocean of Years*, which pertains to what you mentioned about historical records:

> A scientist is trying to prove that the method used for terraforming worlds is not viable, and winds up having to travel to a massive library which stores actual physical copies of documents, rather than digital ones, in the hopes that he can find an ancient research paper which hasn't been redacted/deleted.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents Thanks for the edit; I guess my terrible memory combined all the books into one...

Comment: I just checked the books, each has a "Glossary and Gazetteer of Terms, Places, Ships, Etc.". In the third book, they are following a trial that leads to a museum on The Ruined Planet, Mars, where the ship is trapped by mutated mold. The Grand Library is in Neptune orbit and a copy on the Lunar farside. That was a false lead, the footprints showed the records there untrustworthy.